# Emacsclient server name not recognized

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacsclient

I would like to have `emacsclient` connect to a given Emacs server from command line. Reading the manual [Using Emacs as a Server](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html#Emacs-Server) I thought I could do something like:

```
emacs --eval '(server-start)' --eval "(set-variable 'server-name \"foo\")" --no-splash fileA &
```

and then later:

```
emacsclient -s "foo" -n fileB
```

But this gives error:

```
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
emacsclient: error accessing socket "foo"
```

However, I can do:

```
emacsclient -e '(prin1 server-name)'
```

which gives

```
"foo"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set the name *before* you start the server:

```
emacs --eval '(setq server-name "foo")' --eval '(server-start)' --no-splash fileA &
```